# BizTalk Server 2016: WCF-SAP adapter

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, sap-dotnet-connector

We have updated our environment to BizTalk 2016 and we are using WCF-SAP Send Port to invoke a SAP RFC.

We are receiving this error with NCo connection type. In BizTalk 2009 the same RFC with a Send Port WCF-SAP works perfect:

> Error Description: Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.MetadataException: RFC  could not be resolved against SAP system because its metadata could not be obtained. ---> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: Lookup of function  metadata failed for destination NCoConnection  ---> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException: The only destination NCoConnection62.87.2.23P47PRUEBA002ESono_bztk available failed when retrieving metadata from -- see log for details
>          at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcRepository.findAlternateDestination(Int32& destIndex, Int32& alternativeDestinationsCount, Exception ex)
>          at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcRepository.Execute(RfcFunction function)
>          at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcRepository.LookupFunctionMetadataClassic(String name)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcRepository.LookupFunctionMetadataClassic(String name)
>          at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcRepository.LookupFunctionMetadata(String name)
>          at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcRepository.GetFunctionMetadata(String name)
>          at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.NCo.RfcClientConnection.GetRfcFunctionInterface(String rfcName)
>          at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.InternalRfcMetadata.InitializeRfcFieldsNCo(String originalRfcName, SAPConnection sapConnection)
>          at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPMetadataContract.ResolveOperationMetadata(String operationId, TimeSpan timeout, TypeMetadataCollection& extraTypeMetadataResolved)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Design.MetadataCache.GetOperationMetadata(String uniqueId, Guid clientId, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SapFunctionMetadataNCo.ResolveOperationMetadataUsingSdkNCo(String absoluteName, String displayName, String funcName, String operationNamespace, SAPConnection sapConnection, Boolean isTrfc, MetadataLookup metadataLookup, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Any idea?

Comment: Are you on the latest CU (CU 5) or Feature Pack 3?  Are there any firewalls or proxies that may be blocking the connection?

Comment: Yes, CU5 is installed and there aren't network problems. With ClassicRfc connection mode it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the SAP system is set to `unicode` for this RFC, as stated [here](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2015/05/04/biztalk-wcf-sap-adapter-rfc-idoc_inbound_asynchronous-could-not-be-resolved-against-sap-system-because-its-metadata-could-not-be-obtained/), where the similar problem is solved.

It also doesn't hurt to generate the SAP schema again in Visual Studio, maybe there are some changes.